# How to access (modify, add elements) to an ArrayList/Collection in an Inner class in java?

Tags: java, android, firebase, inner-classes, geofire

I've got this search function to search for specific Users using a firebase Database using GeoFire.

**What i want to do :**

In `GeoQueryEventListener()` & `onKeyEntered`, I want to add each key found to an ArrayList (outside `onKeyEntered()`).

**The problem i have :**

When I print it inside the `onKeyEntered()`, it works.
But as soon as I exit the `GeoQueryEventListener()`, `keysGeolocated` is empty

```
public ArrayList<User> search(GeoFire geoFire, int day, final boolean isBartender, double latitude, double longitude, double radius, double rate, double nightlyRate, double hourlyRate, final String speciality){

    keysGeolocated = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    root = database.getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = root.child("Users");

    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), radius);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new MyGeoListener(keysGeolocated));

    System.out.println("KEYS GEOLOCATED" + keysGeolocated);

    final ArrayList<User> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String key : keysGeolocated){

        Query queryByLocation = usersRef.orderByKey().equalTo(key);
        DatabaseReference refToLocationQuery = queryByLocation.getRef();

        if(checkRefNull(refToLocationQuery) == true) {
            System.out.println("QUERY BY LOCATION NULL");
            continue;
        }

        Query queryByTypeOfUser  = refToLocationQuery.orderByChild("isBarTender").equalTo(isBartender);
        DatabaseReference refToTypeOfUserQuery = queryByTypeOfUser.getRef();

        if(checkRefNull(refToTypeOfUserQuery) == true) {
            System.out.println("QUERY BY TYPE NULL");
            continue;
        }
        Query queryByRate  = refToTypeOfUserQuery.orderByChild("rate").startAt(rate);
        DatabaseReference refToRateQuery = queryByRate.getRef();

        if(checkRefNull(refToRateQuery) == true) {
            System.out.println("QUERY BY RATE NULL");
            continue;
        }

        DatabaseReference finalRef = null;

        if(isBartender == true){

            if(nightlyRate == 0){
                Query queryByPrice  = refToRateQuery.orderByChild("nightlyRate").endAt(nightlyRate);
                finalRef = queryByPrice.getRef();
            }
            else if(hourlyRate == 0){
                Query queryByPrice  = refToRateQuery.orderByChild("hourlyRate").endAt(hourlyRate);
                finalRef = queryByPrice.getRef();
            }

            //TODO Impelement checks for available dates

        }
        else{
            finalRef = refToRateQuery;
        }

        finalRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.getValue()!=null){

                    User userFound = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    if(isBartender == true){
                        Bartender barTenderFound = (Bartender) userFound;
                        if(speciality != null){
                            if(barTenderFound.getSpeciality().contains(speciality)){
                                result.add(barTenderFound);
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            result.add(barTenderFound);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        result.add(userFound);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    return result;
}

public boolean checkRefNull(DatabaseReference ref){

    final boolean[] result = new boolean[1];
    result[0] = false;

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                System.out.println("TEST1");
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue()==null){
                    result[0] = true;
                    System.out.println("TESTTEST");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("TESTTEST TRUE" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
    });

    return result[0];
}

public void setBarTender(boolean barTender){

    this.barTender = barTender;
}
}

class MyGeoListener implements GeoQueryEventListener {

private ArrayList<String> keysGeolocated;

MyGeoListener(ArrayList<String> keysGeolocated){
    this.keysGeolocated = keysGeolocated;
}

@Override
public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
    keysGeolocated.add(key);
}

@Override
public void onKeyExited(String key) {

}

@Override
public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

}

@Override
public void onGeoQueryReady() {

}

@Override
public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

}
}
```

Comment: Change the scope.  Can't be local to that method.

Comment: You are assuming instantaneous results from the listener. If it were synchronous, your call would print the list. Unfortunately, this listener is asynchronous. It will add data inside the list as and when the events fire. You will only see the print work after some time has passed.

Comment: does it have to be an anonymous class? :-}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Class which extends that listener and override all the methods

```
class MyGeoListener extends GeoQueryEventListener{

    private ArrayList<String> keysGeolocated;

    MyGeoListener(ArrayList<String> keysGeolocated){
          this.keysGeolocated = keysGeolocated;
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        keysGeolocated.add(key);
        System.out.println("1111111111 : "+keysGeolocated);
        System.out.println("2222222222 : "+key);
    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyExited(String key) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryReady() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

    }
}
```

Now use this class as follows:

```
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new MyGeoListener(keysGeolocated));
```

The immediate next call will always print no values in the list as the listener is asynchronous and takes time to fill the list.

Try putting the print inside a handler postdelayed with say 30000 milliseconds delay. You will probably see entries in the list as by then the listener events should have fired.

Since an arraylist is mutable and you are passing it's reference, the arraylist in the argument will also be modified when the listener calls.

Good luck and let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer ! Unfortunately, it still does not work :s

Comment: what is the issue now?

Comment: I have updated the post with the current code. When printing  keysGeolocated, i've got : System.out: KEYS GEOLOCATED[] still .. :s

Comment: dude the listener is asynchronous. It will not immediately fill the list. It will take time. You print is an immediate call. Let the listener finish, only then will you have entries inside your list.

Comment: It is what I  thought. But the fact is, I am iterating over the ArrayList just after the print statement (as u can see), and then, I iterate threw and empty arrayList... Is there a way to tell the function to wait for the listener to end before continuing ?

Comment: enclose all those calls in a delay mechanism. delay it by some amount of time by maybe using a handler postdelayed. Maybe even put it in a while loop say :     while(mylist.size()==0 || mylist.size()<100){//waste time}  then immediately followed by your iterations